# Vbs script file is not Executing(Running) while clicking the .vbs file

Tags: vbscript, 32bit-64bit

I have The scenario like deleting files from some particular path and save the deleted file name in .csv file .It is running perfectly when I am running thru developer script inside excel file but it is not running when am  directly executing the .vbs file also I tried using cmd script.

```
InputFilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\vba\FoldersCleanupInput.xlsx"



    ' Create the Excel object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Don't display any alert messages
  objExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0

  ' Open the document as read-only
  On Error Resume Next
  Call objExcel.Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath, False, True)
  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' If you wanted to read all sheets, you could call
  ' objExcel.Worksheets.Count to get the number of sheets
  ' and the loop through each one. But in this example, we
  ' will just read the first sheet.
  Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Set objSheet2 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

  ' Get the number of used rows
  nUsedRows = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  ' Get the number of used columns
  nUsedCols = objSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

  ' Get the topmost row that has data
  nTop = objSheet.UsedRange.Row

  ' Get leftmost column that has data
  nLeft = objSheet.UsedRange.Column

  ' Get the used cells
  Set objCells = objSheet.Cells
  Set objSheet2Cells = objSheet2.Cells

  logpath = objSheet2Cells(1, 2).Value

  numberOfDays = objSheet2Cells(2, 2).Value

  If objFSO.FileExists(logpath) Then

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logpath)

    Else

         Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(logpath, True)

         Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logpath)

    End If




'Open logpath For Output As #1
  ' Dimension the sheet array
  ReDim arrSheet(nUsedRows - 1, nUsedCols - 1)

  ' Loop through each row
  For nRow = 0 To (nUsedRows - 1)
    ' Loop through each column
    For nCol = 0 To (nUsedCols - 1)

              For Each oFile In objFSO.GetFolder(objCells(nRow + nTop, nCol + nLeft).Value).Files

                    If oFile.DateLastModified < (Now() - numberOfDays) Then
                       'Dim i As Integer

                      ' Print #1, "Deleted File Name:" & oFile & "Deleted on:" & Date & " " & Time
                      Set dd = "Deleted File Name:" & oFile & "Deleted on:" & Date & " " & Time
                        objFile.WriteLine dd




                       oFile.Delete (True)

                    End If

                Next

    Next
  Next


'Close #1
  ' Close the workbook without saving
  Call objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)

 ' Quit Excel
  objExcel.Application.Quit
  Close objFile

End Sub
```

Please suggest me to solve the issue .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: but what are you expecting of us? You didn't posted any code.

Comment: I mentioned the .vbs file is not executing if I execute the file. The code has updated.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next`s and see if you get any errors

Comment: Yes, tried as you instructed got below error "bad lines" for the lines   `Set dd = "Deleted File Name:" & oFile & "Deleted on:" & Date & " " & Time
                        objFile.WriteLine dd` so removed those lines and deleted the files but not directly executing .vbs file. Still facing same problem

Comment: Do not post codeblocks in comments, update the code in the question.